# Check for database access. Rails + ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We are using legacy database that goes down unexpectedly. 
This is bad experience for the user and for us.

When doing a simple query, like: `User.find(1)` and database goes down, it will not throw the exception. Just hangs there until database comes back.
Setting timeout did not seem to do any good either.

Running this:
`connected = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection { |con| con.active? }  rescue false` also hangs when connection is lost

Is there any way to check if the database is there before actuall making an ActiveRecord call?

Rails - 4.1.15

Ruby - jruby-9.0.5.0

Database: as400 (db2)

Comment: try to add this to your database.yml pool: 5

Comment: @Boltz0r We have it set for 20 in production. Does not solve the issue

Comment: I'm affraid i can't help then :(

Comment: Have you tried checking if active_record is rocking and rolling via:   " ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active? " or does that hang it up as well?

Comment: If hitting Active Record leads to the drop you can use the "ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection" which will bypass ActiveRecord and allow you to hit the database directly.